# Hide textbox while printing

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

I have a textbox with two command buttons inside that I don't want to show when printing. I've placed the code listed below in the FilePrint and FilePrintDefault Word Commands. If I print using the quick print button, it works perfectly and doesn't print. However, if I print using Ctrl+P and bring up the print dialog, the textbox prints. How can I set it up so that no matter how you print, the textbox won't print? This is on a form letter that several people will use, so I can't just change the Word print settings for everyone, which is why I went with the macro.

```
Sub FilePrint() ' ' FilePrint Macro ' Prints the active document '
    With ActiveDocument
        .Shapes(1).Visible = msoFalse
        .PrintOut Background:=False
        .Shapes(1).Visible = msoTrue
    End With

End Sub  
Sub FilePrintDefault() ' ' FilePrintDefault Macro ' Prints the active document using the current defaults '
    With ActiveDocument
        .Shapes(1).Visible = msoFalse
        .PrintOut Background:=False
        .Shapes(1).Visible = msoTrue
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try putting breakpoint in both functions ?

Comment: ...googling breakpoint...

Comment: breakpoint is set by F9 in the code.

Comment: Ok, running the code through with breakpoint prints the document without the images on it, but when I use Ctrl + P to print, it still prints the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the Word application's `DocumentBeforePrint` event for this purpose. This is where MS explains how to set it up. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821218.aspx

Actually, in order to display the text boxes again after printing, you use the event procedure to call your existing procedures (be sure to disable their calling the event procedure in a loop) and then cancel the printing. So, by whichever way you initialise the printing process the event procedure takes control, runs your two procedures once, and cancels everything else.

Comment: Ok, I've created a new class module (Class1), chosen App as the Object, and DocumentBeforePrint as the procedure. That generated a procedure into which I placed two `call` statements. However, when trying to initialize the new class module (as required in the link you provided), I get this error: Runtime Error 424: Object Required. I'm using the exact code provided in the link, only change is instead of `EventClassModule`, I'm using `Class1`, since that's the name of my new class module.

Comment: New Class Module code: `Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

Call FilePrint
Call FilePrintDefault

End Sub`

Comment: Initialize object code: `Dim X As New Class1
Sub Register_Event_Handler()
 Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub`

Comment: Did you run the proc `Register_Event_Handler`? Normally, one would place `Set X.App = Word.Application` in the Open event procedure so that one doesn't need to remember to run it (unless the code crashes when you still have to run it manually again).

Comment: I pasted it into the same module where the original print code is located (since the link did any module was fine), and ran it there. That's when I got the runtime error. What do you mean place it in the Open event procedure? Assume I'm an idiot and need a kindergarten explanation. :)

Comment: Another question about this: I noticed that the New Class Module is stored in the Normal project. That's local to my network ID, right? So if this is a company-wide document, I'd have to set that macro up for all of them as well. Or am I misunderstanding (which happens alot)?

Comment: In the `ThisDocument` code module select `Document` on the top left and `Open` on the top right. VBA will insert a ready sub which will run whenever the document is opened. (Delete the one which will run on New if it is inserted.) Place all you now have in `Sub Register_Event_Handler()`. Delete the now empty sub. You can call the `Document_Open` sub manually using F5 if there is such need.

Comment: I think you have done a great job, well deserving of my help, but it is time to move on. Award points, if any, and ask about the location of your code in another thread after doing a little research. Basically, a class module is just another module containing code, same as all the others. Word will place all code into the template by default, and the default template is `Normal`. If you need your code to be in the document itself it should be in docm format. It's not difficult, but another subject.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't able to get it to work from the print screen, so I just created a Print commandbutton that called the FilePrint macro from above. So problem solved, I guess.